# Protractor - passing element value from pageObject to spec

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Having trouble passing a value from the pageObject, back to the spec to validate if the value meets the expected assert statement.

pageObject.js

```
this.CampaignTitle = function() {
        element.all(by.repeater('campaign in campaigns')).then(function(campaigns) {
            var title = campaigns[0].element(by.className('campaign-title'));
            title.click();
            return title;
        });
    }
```

spec.js

```
it('Clicking on campaign title should take to campaign report', function() {
    dashboardPage.CampaignTitle();
    expect(dashboardPage.CampaignTitle().getText()).toContain(browser.params.campaignTitle);
});
```

The error I get is

1) Testing campaign dashboard buttons Clicking on campaign title should take to campaign report
  - Failed: Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined

Or if I add title to the

```
  expect(dashboardPage.CampaignTitle(title).getText()).toContain(browser.params.campaignTitle);
```

I get

1) Testing campaign dashboard buttons Clicking on campaign title should take to campaign report
  - Failed: title is not defined

Comment: Couple of question to know your code 1. Where you defined Posts [0]? 2. Why u passing campaigns to function as it's not used anywhere in function?

Comment: Sorry fixed. I just want to get the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use bracket notation for retrieving an element from [ElementArrayFinder](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder), use [.get()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get).  Also I would implement this a little differently, you can do this without using `.then()`;

```
this.CampaignTitle = function() {
    var title = element.all(by.repeater('campaign in campaigns')).get(0).element(by.className('campaign-title'));
    return title;
}
```

spec.js

```
dashboardPage.CampaignTitle().click();
expect(dashboardPage.CampaignTitle().getText()).toContain(browser.params.campaignTitle);
```

Comment: Hey bud, still getting the error relating to  - Failed: dashboardPage.campaignTitle is not a function, really frustrating how it doesn't provide more information, as far as I can tell it is a function!

Comment: Do you have other functions under `dashboardPage` that do work?  Maybe you're not importing/exporting correctly.  Can you update your question with how you create the `dashboardPage` object and how you export it?

Comment: Also, I doubt this is the problem cause it should process the same way, but conventionally functions start with a lower-case letter and constructors start with a capital letter.  So maybe try `var DashboardPage = function()...` and `this.campaignTitle = function()...`

Comment: yes I do, its the only test of many in the file that doesn't work. I think its my weird logic and going to try rework it. The idea was that it selects the item from the repeater, checks if the item title matches what it should and then clicks it.

Answer (score 0):

@theHussle , I hope the below implementation should work.

**pageObject.js**

```
function DashboardPage(){}
DashboardPage.prototype.clickCampaign = function(repeaterName, className, expectedValue, index){
    if(!index){
    index = 0;
    }
    var titleElement = element.all(by.repeater(repeaterName)).get(index).element(by.className(className));
    <if you want you can add some wait to get that element>
    if(expectedValue){
        titleElement.getText().then(function(text){
            expect(text).toContain(expectedValue);
            });
    }
    <if you want you can return titleElement>
};
module.exports = new DashboardPage();
```

**spec.js**

```
var dashBoardPage = require('../pageObject.js');
var repeaterName = 'campaign in campaigns';
var className = 'campaign-title';
var expectedValue = browser.params.campaignTitle;
var index = 0;

<in your test case>

it('Clicking on campaign title should take to campaign report', function(){
    dashBoardPage.campaignTitle();
    });
```

I have tuned the code for better understanding as well as better implementation of pageObject model. you may check and let me know whether it works. But this is how it is working for me. 
Using of 'prototype' is recommended when you are using in separate files.